# Indexing Dataframe with variable in Julia

Tags: indexing, dataframe, julia, keyerror

I want to create a indexed subset of a [DataFrame](http://dataframesjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subsets.html#dataframes) and use a variable inside it. In this case i want to change all -9999 values of the first column to NA's. If I do: `df[df[:1] .== -9999, :1] = NA` it works like it should.. But if i use a variable as the indexer it througs an error (LoadError: KeyError: key :i not found):

```
i = 1
df[df[:i] .== -9999, :i] = NA
```

Comment: Thats the solution! Thank you !

Comment: I'm wondering why you used `:1` as column index name, why not just use an array?

Comment: accept the answer if it has solved your problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:i` is actually a symbol in julia:

```
julia> typeof(:i)
Symbol
```

you can define a variable binding to a symbol like this:

```
julia> i = Symbol(2)
Symbol("2")
```

then you can simply use `df[df[i] .== 1, i] = 123`:

```
julia> df
10×1 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ 2   │
├─────┼─────┤
│ 1   │ 123 │
│ 2   │ 2   │
│ 3   │ 3   │
│ 4   │ 4   │
│ 5   │ 5   │
│ 6   │ 6   │
│ 7   │ 7   │
│ 8   │ 8   │
│ 9   │ 9   │
│ 10  │ 10  │
```

It's worth noting that in your example `df[df[:1] .== -9999, :1]`, `:1` is **NOT** a symbol:

```
julia> :1
1
```

In fact, the expression is equal to `df[df[1] .== -9999, 1]` which works in that there is a corresponding `getindex` method whose argument (`col_ind`) can accept a common index:

```
julia> @which df[df[1].==1, 1]
getindex{T<:Real}(df::DataFrames.DataFrame, row_inds::AbstractArray{T,1}, col_ind::Union{Real,Symbol})
```

Since you just want to change the **first (n)** column, there is no difference between `Symbol("1")` and `1` as long as your column names are regularly arranged as:

```
│ Row │ 1   │ 2   │ 3   │...
├─────┼─────┤─────┼─────┤
│ 1   │     │     │     │...
```